# Comments with effect in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently, while looking over [this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/dev-todo-mvvm-live), on [this line](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/6419d4c523b67d020120fc400ed5a7372e5615f2/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/ViewModelFactory.java#L72) there is `//noinspection unchecked` commentary that suppress the warning "Unchecked cast".

What are other such commentaries? So far I only knew that `@SurpressLint` had such powers.

Answer (score 1):

When suppressing an inspection, IntelliJ IDEA inserts a special comment that tells the code analysis engine to ignore the issues found by this inspection in the specific piece of code.

When disabling an inspection, you just turn it off so the code analysis engine just ignores the code issues found by this inspection.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/suppressing-inspections.html